# Drop "not null" Constraint Error in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm using the following code in Oracle 11g

```
alter table account_creation
drop constraint branch_code;
```

I get an error saying cannot drop constraint non existent constraint but when I check the table the NULL constraint still exists for that particular column
Am I using the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE account_creation
MODIFY (branch_code varchar(10) NULL);
```

Comment: if we don't know the data-type? and want to drop not-null constraint directly by column?